# Why is the representation of the direction of the x and y axes in two dimensions different than in three dimensions?

Tags: mathematics

So I apologize if this question seems a bit nit-picky, but it has bothered me for a while. Usually when a coordinate system is represented in two-dimensions, the x-axis is pointing towards what might be considered "3 o' clock", while the y-axis is at midnight.

[image: two dimensional coordinate system]

However, most representations of 3-dimensional space place the x-axis in the "6 o' clock" direction, and the Y axis in the "3 o'clock" direction.(if you were to lay the clock on the x-y plane).[image: three dimensional coordinate system]

It does not seem like the intuitive way of representing things. Of course a person has the liberty to arrange the axes in whatever fashion they see fit, but the standard seems to be the way shown above. I wonder who thought it was a good idea to arrange the axes in this fashion, and why they chose to do so.

Comment: Afaik it might be even region-dependent. I think any physicist would say for that, it is just a casual selection and all the coordinate systems are equally valid (more exactly, only half of it due to chirality problems).

Comment: It is "quite standard"; see [Axonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axonometry).

Comment: I am not sure this is a history question. The alternative arrangement, with x where y is, and y at the opposite of x, is also widely used, especially in Europe. My guess is that the preference for this arrangement comes from the fact that x and y directions are more widely separated, making the figures with additional elements less clogged.

Comment: Just wait until you see the difference between optical raytracing orientation versus aircraft axes orientation!   It's all a matter of custom.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I know the answer to this.

First, note that both coordinate systems relegate the **vertical axis** to the **last coordinate** (y in 2D, z in 3D); that this feels 'natural' is perhaps a result of Latin script being written horizontally. Now while this fully defines the 2D coordinate system, there are still two possibilities for the 3D system: a so-called **left-handed** system and a **right-handed** system.

[image: 3D coordinate systems]

The reason (I believe) that the right-handed system is standard in both mathematics and physics is that it agrees with the definition of the **vector cross product**, which by convention follows the **right-hand rule**: $\mathbb{x} \times \mathbb{y} = \mathbb{z}$. This definition is fundamental to vector algebra and much of physics.

[image: right-hand rule]

This definition, in turn, follows directly from Hamilton's 1843 formulation or **quaternions**, defined by $ij=k$, $jk=i$ and $ki=j$, by identifying $i, j, k$ with $x, y, z$. Had Hamilton instead defined them by $ji=k$, $kj=i$ and $ik=j$, there would likely have been a left-handed rule instead.

Now the final question of why representations of right-handed 3D coordinates typically show the y axis at "3 o'clock" and the x axis "somewhere past 6 o'clock" (like the picture below, but unlike the first picture), I expect that's simply to separate the axes on the page as far as possible.

[image: 3D coordinate system]

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the arrangement of axes in 3d is due to the conventions we have for the cross product, as the cross product *U x V* is normal to the plane spanned by the vectors $u$ and $v$; normal, suggests vertical or perpendicularity and hence we have the z-axis pointing towards 12 O'Clock.

It is worth noting that the diagrams you've drawn are all for *spatial* diagrams, when one of the axes is time then diagrams modelling classical mechanics usually have time along the 3 O'clock direction and height at the 12 O'clock direction.

However this convention is reversed in special and general relativity.

I suspect, the first convention is simply due to the fact that when we model the trajectory of a thrown stone then this trajectory follows a parabola, and this is the same curve that is drawn on the diagram using this convention. Obviously this is of no relevance to SR/GR.

A final observation is that axes actually define charts and whilst the coordinate frame is special in that the axes are all perpendicular, the notion of a manifold uses charts in a democratic sense - all charts are equally important.